# how do I select second submit button to imply other color

Tags: css

```
.formholder input[type="submit"] {
  background: #84c40b;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  height:31px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
```

how can I select with CSS so i can imply another color to the second submit button?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```
.formholder input[type="submit"]:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
```